# Srcset issue - why cannot I load proper image in my browser?

Tags: srcset

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-24">
        <a href="something">
            <img 
                class="img-responsive"
                alt="something" 
                src="/media/images/bizuteria/promocje-test/top-1024.jpg"
                srcset="/media/images/bizuteria/promocje-test/top-1024.jpg 1024w,
                        /media/images/bizuteria/promocje-test/top-768.jpg 768w,
                        /media/images/bizuteria/promocje-test/top-450.jpg 450w"
                sizes="(max-width: 767px) 450px,
                       (max-width: 1023px) 768px,
                       (max-width: 1283px) 1024px,"
            />
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Why this code always load the bigger image and shrink it to fit the screen? I think that code is proper but somehow it doesn't work. Somehow it works on Safari and Firefox when I shrink screen, but don't want to work on Chrome or actual mobile devices. So what should I do to make it work in Chrome and on phones? May it be a bootstrap img-responsive class that make a problem?

Comment: You are missing the default `src=""`  which is important to always include for devices that don't support `srcset` you can use the 1x image. Chrome might be having an issue without an initial `src` graphic – https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ux/responsive/images

Comment: Well, yeah I do, thanks for pointing that but I deleted it when I started to investigate the issue. It was there before and the result was the same.

Comment: Note that the `<img>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in HTML.

Comment: Thanks Rob, u got the point but I believe this slash is not an issue in here.